# ode23 in MatLab - using optional arguments as input

Tags: matlab, parameters, arguments, argument-passing, ode

I am trying to learn MatLab on my own.  I get most of the concepts regarding solving ODEs, but I am a little unsure about the use of optional arguments as input.  I have created the following function:

```
function xdot = funn(t,x,mu);
if nargin < 3 | isempty(mu)
    mu = 1;
end
xdot = t +mu*x;
```

In addition I have defined:

```
tspan = [0 2];
x0 = 0;
options = odeset('outputfcn','odeplot');
```

What I am unsure about is how to change the variable `mu` when I use the `ode23` function.  I understand that this should be possible through the input of optional arguments, but I can't get it to work.  Say if I write:

```
[t y] = ode23('funn',tspan,x0,options)
```

Then everything computes correctly, and we automatically get `mu` = 1.

But if I want to change this, how do I proceed?  I tried writing the following to set `mu` = 4:

```
[t y] = ode23('funn',tspan,x0,options,4)
```

But then I just get the following:

```
??? Error using ==> funn
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> odearguments at 98
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ==> ode23 at 171
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...
```

I did this based on how I understood the procedure as it is written in my textbook, but obviously I'm doing something wrong here.  If anyone can explain how I go about changing the parameter `mu`, and in general how optional arguments `p1, p2, ...` are used with `ode23` I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is pass data in the function call using [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsgprpq-5.html#bsgprpq-8) functions:

```
[t y] = ode23(@(t,y)funn(t,y,4),tspan,x0,options)
```

Comment: Ah great!  This worked!  Thanks a lot.  The reason I got so confused was that my book states that the syntax for doing this should be: [t y] = ode23('funn',tspan,x0,options,p1,p2,.. . ).  Thus I assumed that the 'mu' variable should be entered in the p1 slot.

Comment: maybe in the older version of matlab... books can be misleading!

Comment: Yes, that could be.  The book is for MatLab 7.8, wheras I use MatLab 7.12.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has nothing to do with `ode23`. The problem seems to be in that you have not listed `varargin` in the function definition of `funn`. It should be:

```
function xdot = funn(t,x,mu,varargin)
```

This way `funn` accepts 3 or more arguments, and you should not get error "Too many input arguments".

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Appreciate your answer. I know get the ode23 call to work, but I get the same answers for the differential equation no matter what number I choose for mu.  If I write ode23('funn',tspan,x0,options,3) or ode23('funn',tspan,x0,options,300), I get exactly the same answer.  What could cause this?

Comment: Your function definition for function `funn` only permits 3 arguments: `t`, `x` and `mu`. In function definition there's no variable defined where fourth argument should enter in `funn` function, so MATLAB gives you an error. You can try calling `funn` directly from MATLAB console: `funn(tspan,x0,options,3)` and you'll get the same error (if you have your variables defined, of course). For optional arguments you need to use `varargin`. With `varargin`, you can check `nargin` to get the total number of arguments and then read `varargin{1}`, `varargin{2}` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I see how calling 'funn' directly in the MATLAB console produces an error just like you say. However, I must admit I am quite new to this, so I still don't understand how I can set the 'mu' parameter upon calling 'ode23'.  My book does not really explain this well.

Comment: Rasman's answer is correct, my answer is incorrect. I'm a bit tired and confused. You don't need `varargin` for optional arguments in this case, it's an alternative way to do it. Your function definition is correct.

Comment: OK.  I really appreciate your input though :).  Thanks a lot!